# Query Uniswap v3 unclaimed fees without external API?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3

I'm a little bit confused because the Uniswap v3 Nonfungible Positions Manager has a `positions` function, that's supposed to return `token0Owed` and `token1Owed`, which is (I think in not just my case) is always zero, regardless of how many fees have accumulated already. All the answers on Stackexchange point to now paid 3rd party services to query this info.

Where do those services get their data from?

I really wanna get down to this and query / calculate it directly from the blockchain. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `token0Owed` and `token1Owed` doesn't return the collectables fees. My two cents:

I wrote a function that perform a static call passing the maximum collectable value in other to see how much is pending to be collected.

```
export const calculatePendingFees = async (
  tokenId: number,
  recipient: string,
  amount0Max: BigNumber,
  amount1Max: BigNumber,
  chainId: number
) => {
  try {
    const params = {
      tokenId: tokenId,
      recipient: recipient,
      amount0Max: amount0Max,
      amount1Max: amount1Max,
    }

    const nonfungible = new ethers.Contract(
      NONFUNGIBLE_POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS[chainId],
      Nonfungiblepositionmanager.abi,
      PROVIDER[chainId]
    )

    const feesGenerated = await nonfungible.callStatic.collect(params)
    return feesGenerated
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message, "calculate fees error")
  }
}
```

For `amount0Max`and `amount1Max`you can use this:

```
const MAX_UINT128 = BigNumber.from(2).pow(128).sub(1)
```

This function will return to you the uncollected fees :)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I've come across a similar solution, but I thought this does a transaction, I haven't used callStatic before.